# ¿Cómo agregar texto al textarea más de una vez con un botón?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero agregar texto a un textarea tantas veces yo le haga clic al botón pero este solo se agrega una vez, después ya no deja agregarlo.

Código:

```js
let enviar = document.getElementById('id')
enviar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let area = document.getElementById('area')
  let saludo = "texto"
  console.log("hola")
  area.innerHTML = saludo;
})
```

```html
 

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <textarea name="" id="area"></textarea>
      <button id="id">enviar</button>
    </body>

    </html>
```

El resultado esperado era darle clic, aparece texto, eliminar texto por parte del usuario, volver a darle clic y que aparezca el texto otra vez.

Comment: concatena y no reemplaces `area.innerHTML += saludo;`

Comment: pero si lo eliminas ya no agrega nada

Comment: a que te refieres con eliminar?

Comment: darle clic al textarea y quitarlo con la tecla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El atributo `innerHTML` sirve para insertar código html y es muy usado al momento de tener templates, pero en tu caso no quieres insertar un html, sino que quieres cambiar el valor del elemento, por lo que tienes que usar su atributo `value`

```js
let enviar = document.getElementById('id')
enviar.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let area = document.getElementById('area')
  let saludo = "texto"
  console.log("hola")
  area.value = saludo;
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <textarea name="" id="area"></textarea>
      <button id="id">enviar</button>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Me sirvió muchas gracias.